# Paragraph output using Windows findstr

Tags: grep, findstr

How can I achieve the equivalent of `grep -p` using Windows `findstr` (or other Windows tools)?

In case it's not obvious, `grep -p` outputs the whole paragraph when it finds a match, that is all the lines between blank lines. I want to achieve the same using only functions that are part of Windows (I have a version of grep on Windows that I have no idea where I got it from, that has `-p`).

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Windows tool `findstr` doesn't work exactly like `grep -p` does. But we can get a similar result by using `findstr` together with other Windows tools.

You may try this approach using `powershell`

```
$paragraph = @()
Select-String -Path "YOUR_FILE_PATH" -Pattern "YOUR_SEARCH_PATTERN" | ForEach-Object {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Line)) {
        if ($paragraph.Count -gt 0) {
            $paragraph
            $paragraph = @()
        }
    } else {
        $paragraph += $_.Line
    }
}
if ($paragraph.Count -gt 0) {
    $paragraph
}
```

Comment: Gosh - powershell seems a bit heavy-weight for a simple little cmd file. Is that really the only way? Actually looking at your answer, seems like you're just using powershell for post-processing, just like rexx I guess. So presumably batch can do this just as well.

Comment: `PowerShell` provides a robust solution and Very powerful. Non-`DOS` guys always feel like this. Programmers of Pre-Windows Era prevail over Windows Era generation due to their command over` DOS`.
And yes, there are alternative approaches to achieving same task, including a `Batch` process. Please Remember, **There is a Soultion to Every Problem, And there are More than one Soultion for every Problem**

Comment: And Do not Forget to **Upvote** and Mark the Response as **Accepted**

Comment: I know there are likely to be many solutions to this problem. That was why I asked for another one. I will wait an see what other solutions appear.

Comment: Meanwhile **Upvote** the answer you have already received, if it works the way you want. You can do the same to other responses also, And **Accept** only the one that works best for you